# Does a non-vested company contribution count towards the annual 401(k) limit?

Tags: united-states, 401k

My company makes a significant match to my 401(k) contributions. Unfortunately, that match is not vested till the middle of next year. Would this contribution count against the annual 2013 contribution limit of $17500?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Employers' match doesn't count towards *your* annual limit (the $17500 this year), but it does count towards the *overall* limit ($51K this year).

For details on these limits see [the IRS news release](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-news/IR-12-077.pdf).

Comment: And the vested/not vested makes no difference, correct? eg they can't deposit, say, 200k but claim it has a 4 year vest.

Comment: @Joe yes, vesting is not a factor for these limitations.